# Scrape text within div tag having some other tags with text - only scrape text of the div tag

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wanted to scrape text from the div tag but it has sub tags which also having some texts each but when I tried to scrape text, all texts were scraped. I wanted to ignore texts from the sub tags of the `div`. only wanted to scrape text from the `div`. Here is what I already tried.

```
import bs4



content = '''<div class="_6ku5"><h4 class="_6ku6">Some Text Here.</h4><ul class="_6ku7"><li>Another Text Here</li><li>also text here</li><li>Be alert</li><li>Play safely</li></ul><br/><h4 class="_6ku6">score:</h4>43<h4 class="_6ku6">Last Updated:</h4>04 Agoosto 2020= date</div>'''


sp = bs4.BeautifulSoup(content, "html5lib")

mob = sp.find_all("div", class_="_6ku5")

print('\n\n',mob[0].get_text(),'\n\n')

print(mob[0].find_all(class_="_6ku6")[2].get_text())
```

in the above I only wanted to scrape the text `Last Updated:04 Agoosto 2020` in my attempt I can scrape `Last Updated` but not the date. ***How can I achieve this?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import bs4



content = '''<div class="_6ku5"><h4 class="_6ku6">Some Text Here.</h4><ul class="_6ku7"><li>Another Text Here</li><li>also text here</li><li>Be alert</li><li>Play safely</li></ul><br/><h4 class="_6ku6">score:</h4>43<h4 class="_6ku6">Last Updated:</h4>04 Agoosto 2020= date</div>'''


sp = bs4.BeautifulSoup(content, "html5lib")

last_updated = sp.find_all("h4", class_="_6ku6")[-1].get_text(strip=True)

date = sp.find('div', class_="_6ku5").findAll(text=True, recursive=False)[-1].split('=')[0]

print(last_updated + date)
```

Output:

```
Last Updated:04 Agoosto 2020
```